# Как принять файл со скрипта php, запускаемого через shell_exec()?

Tags: php, mpdf

Суть такова, есть скрипт-прослойка,запускаемый с GET параметрами, из него идет вызов целевого скрипта через nohup(cкрипту нельзя умирать по времени):

```
$from = $_REQUEST['from'];
$to = $_REQUEST['to'];
$u_ids = $_REQUEST['u_ids'];
$manager_id = $_REQUEST['manager_id'];
$lang = $_REQUEST['lang'];
$mail = $_REQUEST['mail'];
$usersIDS = explode(',', $u_ids);
var_dump(
    shell_exec('nohup php /mpdf/pdf5.php "'.$from.'" "'.$to.'" "'.$u_ids.'" "'.$manager_id.'" "'.$lang.'" "'.$mail.'" "'.$usersIDS.'" >/dev/null 2>&1')
);
```

Сейчас возвращается NULL.

В целевом скрипте идет генерация pdf файла через mpdf 6й версии. И вывод(должен быть запрос на сохранение готового пдф файла):

```
$mpdf->Output('Pay Period.pdf', 'D');
```

Как прислать файл на клиент(выдать тот же запрос на сохранение файла,когда скрипт отработает)?

Comment: Записать в БД где он хранится и вернуть ID записи. А так вообще-то это долгосрочная работа, поэтому её лучше организовать через очередь задач, когда к вам в основную программу будет callback с данными о сгенерированном отчете. Смотрите Gearman или Laravel Queues

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Тойсть, фактически,сохранить файл на сервере,записать идентификатор,потом,когда процесс создания закончится, вернуть id и отдать файл с сервера? В сторону Gearman пока не смотрели,так как проект горящий

Answer (score 0):

Решил следующим образом:

1. при старте генерации отчета сохранял будущий путь к pdf в
   переменную;
2. Во время генерации показывал loader;
3. Проверял с интервалом существование файла на сервере. Когда файл
   существует, останавливал loader, очищал интервал и отправлял уже сохраненный путь к
   pdf браузеру, делая `window.location`;